# submit button is not working when i fill all inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with some fields, for secure passing and decreasing spam posting i embed some JS code for disabling the submit button till all fields are filled.

The problem is when i fill all fields still submit button is disabled.

**JS Code**

```
function checkform() {
    var f = document.forms["theform"].elements;
    var cansubmit = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if ("value" in f[i] && f[i].value.length == 0)
            cansubmit = false;
    }

    document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = !cansubmit;
}
window.onload = checkform;
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" class="ara-form" name="theform">
                <header>Enter Job Details</header>

                <fieldset>                  
                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Job Title" name="positiontitle">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Organization / Company Name" name="companyname">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Location" name="location" >
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Job Category  e.g. IT" name="jobcategory">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Employment Type  e.g. Full Time" name="employmenttype">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Salary  e.g. 5000$" name="salary">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Duration  e.g. Permanent" name="duration">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i> 
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Timing  e.g. 8 AM - 4 PM" name="timing">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Nationality" name="nationality">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Number of Vacancy  e.g. 2 Post(s)" name="numberofvacancy">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Experience  e.g. 3 Years" name="experience">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Closing Date" id="datepicker" name="closingdate">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Gender" name="gender">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Education  e.g. Bachelor" name="education">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                     </div>             
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>  

                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Tell us about your company background
                            <textarea id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"  name="background" placeholder="Tell us about your company background"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>                  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Job Summary
                            <textarea id="editor2" rows="10" cols="80"  name="summary" placeholder="Job Summary"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Job Duties and Responsibilities
                            <textarea id="editor3" rows="10" cols="80"  name="duty"  placeholder="Job Duties and Responsibilities"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Qualification Needed
                            <textarea id="editor4" rows="10" cols="80"  name="qualification"  placeholder="Qualification Needed"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Skills Needed
                            <textarea id="editor5" rows="10" cols="80"   name="skill" placeholder="Skills Needed"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Submission Guideline
                            <textarea id="editor6" rows="10" cols="80"   name="submission" placeholder="Submission Guideline"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                                        <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Words for making search easy e.g IT | Officer | Manager | ...
                            <textarea id="editor7" rows="10" cols="80"   name="search" placeholder="Words for making search easy e.g IT | Officer | Manager | ... "></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                </fieldset>
                <footer>
                    <p>Fill all fields to activate the submit button.</br>
                    Thanks</p><i class="fa fa-check" style="float: right; position: relative; right: 22px; color: white; z-index: 1; padding-top: 23px;"></i><input 
                    class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"

                    id="submitbutton" />


                    </footer>
            </form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yPvg/53/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have added `onKeyup="checkform()"` for all the `input` tags. Please do the same for all the `textarea`s as well. Hope this solves.

Edit: Use the following code.

```
function checkform() {
    var f = document.forms["theform"].elements;
    var cansubmit = true;


    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        console.log(f[i].className);
        if(f[i].type=="text" && f[i].className=="mandatory-field"){
            if ("value" in f[i] && f[i].value.length == 0){
                cansubmit = false;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = !cansubmit;
}
window.onload = checkform;
```

Add a class 'mandatory-field' to the input fields which want to be mandatory field.

for example-

```
<input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Job Title" name="positiontitle" class="mandatory-field">
```

Comment: thanks it worked i will tick it as approved, but can i just assign some fields to be filled by their names. like just fields like positiontitle and background should be filled, and the rest can be empty.

Comment: @user3675179 Do you mean you don't want all the text fields to be mandatory? Yes you can do that as well. You can add a class or attribute to those field which are mandatory and check those fields only.

Comment: I will appreciate if you guide me through, i am not skilled like you in php.

Comment: @user3675179 check now.

Comment: Yes. Do you want me to write that logic for you?

Comment: Thanks, i will appreciate it

Comment: Please try f[i].attributes["name"]=="positiontitle" instead of f[i].className=="mandatory-field"

Comment: Thanks Rupam, and sorry it was night so i couldn't answer it. with the name attribute it is not working.

Comment: @user3675179 Please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/UD3nA/. Do let me know if it works and also please accept.

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate your help. It works in jsfiddle but not in  local server, the problem that i found is CKEditor [link](http://ckeditor.com/) because if i disable CKEditor in textareas then the ways that you said work good but when it is activate CKEditor then textares doesn't work.

Comment: can you please help me to find a solution for this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like to find a solution but I've not used CKEditor in any of my project. I've zero knowledge on that.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me an alternative, because when i copy a content in textarea then the style of the contents removes, so i used ckeditor to maintain the style and save it to mysql database with the same styles

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see an alternative. You probably need to play with the rendered dom to validate this.

Comment: Thanks, i will appreciate if you guide me through

Comment: Please try yourself and then if you are not able to solve please share your code using some source.

Comment: Thanks Rupam, actually i search for this easy almost for three days, and no success.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery.

```
function checkform() {
   var f = document.forms["theform"].elements;
   var cansubmit = true;

   for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if ("value" in f[i] && f[i].value.length == 0)
            cansubmit = false;
   }

   if(cansubmit){
        $('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');    
   }
   else{
        $('#submitbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){checkform();});
```

Please see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mizanurahma/r2B9Y/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `window.onload` - there's no event listener to check the status of the form fields on subsequent events. I would recommend binding the function to `keyup` or similar so that it will validate on keyboard input being detected and change DOM state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but how, because in this case we can just call window.onload

Comment: First of all - I hadn't noticed your inline JS, that's bad practice, but I see what you're trying to do. Essentially what I'm saying is that the `onload` is only called once - [reasoning here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload). I would add a listener to validate the form either continuously on 'keyup' events within the form - to undisable the button - or leave the button enabled and run a validation when clicked. If the form is invalid, warn the user and `preventDefault()` to stop the form being submitted. These have worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would bind an event to the form being submitted, then you could go through and validate the fields and if the form is fine to submit, allow it to continue normally, otherwise I'd return false to stop the submission at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your event only trigger once.

Try this

```
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').onchange = checkform;
```